# Stochastic Processes: Randomly Stopped Sums *vs* the sum of I.I.D. Random Variables? (For Finding PGF's)

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability-generating-fn

So I'm studying Stochastic Processes (specifically PGF's).

I see two definitions but I don't seem to know how to differentiate between them properly.

---

**Theorem 1**

Suppose $X_1, ... , X_n$ are *independent* random variables, and let $Y = X_1 + ... + X_n$. Then,

$$G_Y(s) = \prod_{i=1}^n G_{X_i}(s)$$

**Theorem 2**

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with common PGF $G_X$. Let $N$ be a random variable, independent of the $X_i$'s with PGF $G_N$, and let $T_N = X_1 + ... + X_N = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$. Then the PGF of $T_N$ is:

$$G_{T_N}(s) = G_N (G_X(s))$$

---

I'm not sure how to differentiate between these theorems. The first tells me that the sum of iid R.V.'s can be written as the product of their PGF's. But the second theorem also shows a sum of random variables.. Are they just different ways to express the sum or is there some condition I'm not grasping?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the first case, $N$ is fixed, so you do know how many elements are in the sum.  In the second case, $N$ is random, so you don't know how many elements are in the sum.  You can imagine that there's somehow "more randomness" in the second case, so the distribution of the sum will be different, as will the MGF, PGF, etc.